# Format HTML in plain text mail format (RoR)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

I'm trying to set a html user sign in a plain text rails mail view.

When I was using multi part, html_safe was working, but when I changed it to a single format view, it doesn't work, even on a html partial.

Here's the code:

```
send_proposals_email.text.erb -

<%= @greeting %>,
  ...
<%= @user.sign.html_safe %>
```

And it gets me a

```
<p>Atenciosamente,</p>

<p>Leandro Pons Malheiros</p>
```

Anyone knows a way to avoid spam and make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this `strip_tags`?

`strip_tags(@greeting)`

[stip_tags Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-strip_tags)